# Android: Revisiting Garbage Collection: View allocation sticks around after onDestroy

Tags: android, garbage-collection

I found this really old post which basically sums up my question:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/QsSjuB62Kow

The outcome (hackbod/mark/romain answer) of that thread seems somewhat unsatisfactory to me, considering the OP notes that this did not happen prior to version 1.5.

The long and short:

```
Activity starts service.
finish is called on Activity.
Application's memory allocation remains constant
(despite views being garbage collected either eventually or manually)
```

The reason I bring this up.

I have a service that is started on boot via a broadcast receiver, and uses about 5 MB.

When my activity is started, memory allocation jumps to 40MB (I have a lot of views going on, so that is to be expected).  The activity finishes, and the service is still running (by design).  Memory allocation remains high, which I would consider to be a problem.

In this activity, nulling everything `onDestroy`, iterating through all views and arrays and nulling, `System.gc()` (yes I know it just suggests), force GC, nor opening as many apps as I can to bring total device free memory below 20% does nothing to this allocation.  It remains constant at 40MB even though there are no traces of the activity remaining (spent lots of time in MAT).

How can I get this allocation to go from 40MB down to 5MB?  OR is this just not the Android way of doing things?

I have gone to extreme measures to ensure that context or objects are not leaked from activity to service/etc (in fact there are no references between either except through shared preferences).  If you see the extremely basic example in the original post, I guess that would help shed light on the situation.

If I decouple the service from the activity, and either run just the service or just the activity, but never both at the same time, memory allocation is predictable.  The service never consumes more than 5MB and the activity never more than 35MB.  And when either onDestroy are called, the memory no longer shows up as allocated for each.

I have noted the same behavior in both Android 2.3 and 4.x.

Maybe I am missing something fundamental here, or perhaps this is just a dumb question.

Comment: Have you tried running DDMS and using the memory allocation feature to see what is going on? I think what you will find is that the bulk of the memory usage is the basic overhead of your classes and resource file (R) - and you cannot GC them. In particular, review the static class members - these may reference caches or other memory structures that won't GC because they are referenced.

Answer (score 1):

I poured through MAT for hours and as Andrew suggested, some of the Activity's resources were still sticking around as long as the service was running.

For anyone struggling with this, I found a cheap easy fix.

Simply spawn your service in a separate process.

This "sorta" did the trick, and now when my Activity's `onDestroy` is called, the memory used by the Activity (in my case 35MB) is moved to "cached process" and the active running service returns to what it was previously (in my case 5MB).

In your manifest:

The `android:process` attribute being the key here.  More about that here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html